# how to check nonblocking socket timeout WITHOUT select

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

i got some legacy code using: **nonblocking** socket, **select** for timeout, **read**(2) and **write**(2).
Now it occasionally failed due to select/1024 fd limits. so i need to replace the select.

It seems RCVTIMEO and SNDTIMEO can also check timeout but they work for blocking mode, and it impacts too much to change from non-blocking to blocking.

So is there any other best practice to check timeout for **nonblocking** socket(no **select**)? Or i have to get some timer/nanosleep to solve this?

Comment: To go with the answer from ciphor, check out http://linux.die.net/man/7/epoll

Comment: It is worth mentioning that your OS also has a file descriptor limit which is probably set to 1024. I also recommend something like `libev`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg see my comments on Andy Ross

Comment: @EricdesCourtis limits.comf? i got this done.

Comment: Regarding the comment from Eric, the limit of 1024 descriptors to `select` is actually often hard-coded (search for `FD_SETSIZE`). This means that changing the system limit often isn't enough, but you have to `#define FD_SETSIZE` before including `<sys/select.h>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`poll()` is essentially a drop-in replacement for using `select()`, but does not have the 1024 file descriptor limit.  You will have to change your code slightly to create an array of `struct pollfd` structures instead of using `fd_set`s, but the overall structure of the code should not have to change.

Comment: it seems i just forgot there is a poll... "do not change the overall structore of code" is exactly what i want. Sometimes you just have to fix something asap...

Answer (score 3):

epoll is a better solution than select, which is not limited to 1024 descriptors.

In fact, you can use [libevent](http://libevent.org) or [libev](http://libev.schmorp.de/) to handle low level asynchronous socket I/O, they are the so-called "best practice" for async I/O.

Comment: well, i am just maintaining these code and there is not too much choice. Hope i get chance to introduce these best practive in future.

Answer (score 2):

The poll() system call will take a timeout and doesn't have a fixed limit of file descriptors.  If you really have 1000 open descriptors though, you would probably be better served by epoll(), which is more complicated to use but has much better scaling characteristics.

Comment: well the original **select** is actually to check the nonblocking socket status when **EAGAIN** or **EWOULDBLOCK** received during read/write. I am not experienced here and i think it is a little waste to use epoll to check **EAGAIN** when loop reading/writing, since it may just monitor one socket.